# Comparing the values of two dict_values based on certain criteria

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries that I'd liked to compare their dict_values based on certain criteria, say the value at index 0 and 2 on their respective dict_values have to be the same to be considered equal.

This code works:

```
a = dict()
b = dict()
a[1,3] = 5, 6, 7
b[1,4] = 5, 9, 7
a_tuple = (list(a.values()))[0]
b_tuple = (list(b.values()))[0]
if a_tuple[0] == b_tuple[0] and a_tuple[2] == b_tuple[2]:
   print('Equal')
```

Is there a shorter/efficient way to do this ?.

Thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Comparing based on the first value in a dictionary (like you're doing) is fishy since there really is no first value in a dictionary (they're unordered).  -- Of course, if they have only 1 element it works out great (since an unordered set of 1 element has a well defined order -- weird...), but it will likely not work if you have more than one element in the dict.

Comment: Inherited legacy code per say, there is only one element in the dict_values for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is much better, but the following should work:

```
import operator
import sys

py3k = sys.version_info[0] > 2

a = dict()
b = dict()
a[1,3] = 5, 6, 7
b[1,4] = 5, 9, 7

if(py3k):
  a_tuple = next(iter(a.values()))
  b_tuple = next(iter(b.values()))
else:
  a_tuple = a.values()[0]
  b_tuple = b.values()[0]

cmp_key=operator.itemgetter(0,2)
if cmp_key(a_tuple) == cmp_key(b_tuple):
  print('Equal')
```

The comparison is a little more clean and I use `next` and `iter` to get the first tuple in the dictionary if using python 3.

Of course, the better solution would be change the data structure so you're not constantly dealing with dictionaries with only 1 item.

Comment: I try to learn something every day (I didn't actually know if `iter` would work before I tried it).

Comment: @JohnX -- Also note that `next(iter(a.values()))` will work on python2 as well, it's probably just less efficient than indexing, but might be worth using to get rid of the stupid `if-else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not much difference, only optimization i found is
a_tuple = a.values()[0]
b_tuple = b.values()[0]

Actually dict.values gives you tuple only. You are convrting it to list and then again to tuple

Comment: If using python3, you need to convert it to some other type.