# Why dictionary values comparison doesn't work in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare the values of two dict if the frequency of elements are the same or not, elements can be different but their frequency should be the same.

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}

# when I do a comparison of values, it doesn't work

print(dict1.values())
print(dict2.values())

if dict1.values() == dict2.values():
    print("Equal")
else:
    print("Not Equal")
```

Output:

```
dict_values([1, 2, 3])
dict_values([1, 2, 3])
Not Equal
```

So even though the output of dict.values() is same but they are not equal.
Is this comparison not allowed and is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html?highlight=dict_values#c.PyDict_Values) `PyDict_Values` returns a `PyListObject` instance. You can see it with `type(dict1.values)` which outputs `<class 'dict_values'>`.

As you can't compare most objects according to their values, to be able to perform a comparison you can convert `dict1.values()` to a list or iterate through it.

You will find several possibilies in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585641/comparing-the-values-of-two-dict-values-based-on-certain-criteria).

Answer (score 4):

The method `dict.values()` does not return a list but a [view into the dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views). You need to consume it fully to obtain a list that can be compared:

```py
if list(dict1.values()) == list(dict2.values()):
    print("Equal")
else:
    print("Not Equal")
```

Note that this comparison will only work if values are ordered the same in both dictionaries. You might want to ensure order by sorting:

```py
if sorted(dict1.values()) == sorted(dict2.values()):
    print("Equal")
else:
    print("Not Equal")
```

As `sorted()` returns a list, we don't need the `list()` call anymore.

Comment: `values` doesn't return a generator, as we can see with `next(d.values())` failing.

Comment: Thanks, my wording was lazy, corrected it.

Comment: If the reason `dict1.values() == dict2.values()` and even `dict1.values() == dict1.values()` evaluate to `False` is because they are ***views***, why do `dict1.keys() == dict1.keys()` and `dict1.items() == dict1.items()` both evaluate to `True`?  They are views also, right?

Comment: The reason is that those are set-like, and therefore implement, amongst others, the == operator. Note that for items(), this is only valid if all values are hashable (stated in the documentation that is linked in the answer). Being a view does not prevent offering features that a list or other collection would offer. It only means that you cannot expect them like OP did.

Answer (score 3):

[This is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

> An equality comparison between one dict.values() view and another will
> always return False. This also applies when comparing dict.values() to
> itself

Perhaps because they provide a dynamic view, you need to "freeze" the values taken from the view and then compare. One way is to cast them to tuples at the comparison instant:

```
>>> tuple(dict1.values()) == tuple(dict2.values())
True
```